# Applicative style for infix operators?

Tags: haskell, applicative, infix-operator

Is there a way to make applicative uses of `<$>` and `<*>` look nice when dealing with infix operators? I think that

```
((++) <$> a <*> ((++) <$> b <*> c ))
```

looks much more cluttered then

```
a ++ b ++ c
```

so I wonder if there is a nicer way.

Comment: If they are all the same operator, you could use `foldr1 (liftA2 (++)) [a, b, c]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(<++>) = liftA2 (++)
a <++> b <++> c
```

or

```
liftA2 (++) a $ liftA2 (++) b c
```

Comment: yup - add another pair of angle brackets.

Answer (score 6):

See Thomas Davie's [InfixApplicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/InfixApplicative) package, which provides a general syntactic trick, rather than having to define a new operator for each lifting.

Comment: The documentation is a bit mangled. I *think* the OP's example would translate as `a <^(++)^> (b <^(++)^> c)` --- can you confirm/deny?

Answer (score 3):

[SHE](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/) lets you write

```
(|a ++ (|b ++ c|)|)
```

if that's any use. Of course, there's some overhead to introducing a preprocessing layer.